# derivative integral $\int_0^{x^2} \sin(t^2)dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I want to know how I derivative this integral: $$\int_0^{x^2} \sin(t^2)dt$$
what are the steps to derivative  it?

Comment: the fundamental theorem of calculus is the key.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**:

The function $$f(x) =\int_{0}^{x^2} \sin(t^2) dt$$ is in fact a compositum of two functions:

- $g(x) = x^2$
- $h(x) = \int_0^x \sin(t^2) dt$

Both $g$ and $h$ have very simple derivatives, and since $f(x)=h(g(x))$, you can use a certain rule to calculate $f'(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x) = \displaystyle \int_{0}^{x^2} \sin(t^2)dt$, then using the Chain Rule: $f'(x) = \sin((x^2)^2)\cdot \dfrac{d}{dx}(x^2) = 2x\sin(x^4)$

Comment: when do you put the integral's values? before or after the derivative?

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$\int_0^{x} \sin(t^2)dt=F(x)$$
By Fundamental theorem of calculus: $F'(x)=\sin(x^2)$. Here we have $F(x^2)$ and, by chain rule:
$$(x^2)' F'(x^2)=2x \sin x^4$$